# What shall I use: Google Datastore or Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a project on my Final year at uni and this will be an Android application.
Basically, the "company" updates the database with jobs to be done around the country. Its field workers will use the app to display the jobs available in their location. Workers then select the jobs they are committing to do and send the selection back to database.

I would like to use Google App Engine for that and I am just studying it at the moment.
I came across two methods how to store the data on GAE: Datastore and Cloud SQL.

Personally, I would like to use NoSql Datastore in order to experiment and learn it.

What would you suggest me to use for my use case?

What are the pros and cons of using both mentioned methods?

If I go with Google Datastore, is this guide good for me to start with? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Comment: Cloudsql requires billing (ie Credit Card) in production the datastore doesn't for smaller apps.  That might be a deciding factor in it's own right ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would say both will work. If you want to discover the Google Datastore then go for it.
But I would suggest you have a look at [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), this library is excellent to make you the things easier with this technology.

Answer (score 1):

go with Google App engine Database. its very efficient to use. yes tat document is enough to start.